# Convert a haskell function to work with byte strings

Tags: function, haskell, binary

Ive got this code which takes an integer 'n', and a list, then splits the list into 'n' lists.

```
chunk n xs = chunk' i xs
  where
    chunk' _ [] = []
    chunk' n xs = a : chunk' n b where (a,b) = splitAt n xs
    i = ceiling (fromIntegral (length xs) / fromIntegral n)
```

And this is an example of how it works:

```
*Main> chunk 5 [1..10]
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
```

Ive been trying to get this to work with the Data.ByteString library but cant figure it out.

This is the code ive been trying to use.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
B.readFile "meow.txt" >>= (\x -> return $ chunk 4 x)
```

And this is the error that it gives me:

```
<interactive>:402:51:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a10]'
                with actual type `B.ByteString'
    In the second argument of `chunk', namely `x'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `chunk 4 x'
    In the expression: return $ chunk 4 x
```

It appears to be a type mismatch problem, im assuming because of the `fromIntegral`. Is there any way to get the chunk function to accept byte strings?

My goal with this function is to strictly accept a binary file of arbitrary length, then split it into 4 pieces of approximately equal length without losing any of the data in the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Byte strings are not lists. You will have to write a separate function.

But it is a simple translation. Assuming you have `import qualified Data.ByteString as B`, then

```
chunkBytes :: Int -> B.ByteString -> [B.ByteString]
chunkBytes n xs = chunk' i xs
  where
    chunk' n xs
        | B.null xs = []
        | otherwise = a : chunk' n b where (a,b) = B.splitAt n xs
    i = ceiling (fromIntegral (B.length xs) / fromIntegral n)
```

Comment: This code still spits out a few errors and doesnt compile:      `Couldn't match expected type 'B.ByteString' with actual type '[t0]'
    In the second argument of 'B.splitAt', namely 'xs'
    In the expression: B.splitAt n xs
    In a pattern binding: (a, b) = B.splitAt n xs`

Comment: My apologies. It is a simple translation, but apparently not so simple that I can get away without checking it. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the [listlike](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListLike-3.1.6) package. It creates an unified API for working with lists, `ByteString`s, `Text` etc. So you could write:

```
import qualified Data.ListLike as LL

chunk :: (Integral n, LL.ListLike l a) => n -> l -> [l]
chunk n xs = chunk' i xs
  where
    chunk' n xs | LL.null xs = []
                | otherwise = a : chunk' n b where (a,b) = LL.splitAt n xs
    i = ceiling (fromIntegral (LL.length xs) / fromIntegral n)
```

Answer (score 1):

ByteString is not a list, so you can't traverse it with `Prelude.splitAt`, which is exported from Data.List, you should use `B.splitAt` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching is low-level, it strictly uses the value constructors to match it. [] and (:) are values constructor for list type [a]. Bytestrings contructors are different, and usually not very useful for users.

We have seen some interest in a higher level form of matching, based on the shape of the values, for example "traversable" values. But there isn't any implementation yet, as far as I know.